# Why the method of Lagrange multipliers fails in this case?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

I need to minimize and maximize $f(x,y,z)=xy^2z^3$, given that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 6$.

According to the [Lagrange multipliers calculator](https://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/calculus-3/lagrange-multipliers-calculator/?f=xy%5E2*z%5E3%2C&g=x%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2%3D6&h=), there is an infinite number of points, where the function achieves the zero value.
But zero is neither minimum, nor maximum: $f(2,1,1)=2$, $f(-2,1,1)=-2$.

Why did the method fail to find the real maximum and minimum, and find the points, that are neither maximum, nor minimum?

Comment: Note that there is neither a maximum nor a minimum of $f(x)=x^3$ when $x=0$

Comment: I know that. The question is why does the method fail?

Comment: @AndrewFount The method doesn't fail, the online calculator fails in this case.

Comment: The calculator on eMathHelp appears to get "distracted" by the fact that every point on the constraint sphere with one of its coordinates equal to zero gives a function value of zero.  It may be using a technique that searches for extremal points that gets into difficulty when the function has "degenerate" critical points. WolframAlpha does produce the absolute maxima and minima that are found from the Lagrange equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the online calculator fails, indeed from the given equation for the case $xyz \neq 0$ we find by elimination of $\lambda$

- $2x^2=y^2$
- $2z^2=3y^2$

that is from the constraint

- $x=\pm 1$
- $y=\pm \sqrt 2$
- $z=\pm \sqrt 3$

To check this result we can use the constraint to obtain the equivalent problem

$$g(x,z)=xz^3(6-x^2-z^2)$$

which indeed has maximum at $(x,z)=(\pm 1,\pm \sqrt 3)$ and minimum at $(x,z)=(\mp 1,\pm \sqrt 3)$.

Comment: But the solution to the system is the same as given by Wolframalpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+2ux%2By%5E2z%5E3%3D0%2C+2y%28u%2Bxz%5E3%29%3D0%2Cz%282u%2B3xy%5E2z%29%3D0%2Cx%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2-6%3D0

Comment: @AndrewFount Try to ask for “more solutions”.

Comment: @AndrewFount WA is not interpreting your "u" as something to be manipulated like a Lagrange multiplier.  It is simply treating it as one of four variables in your system of equations; it find that the way to deal with it is to set it to zero.  This may be exactly because of the nature of the function, being equal to zero in all coordinate planes.  The maxima and minima (including local ones) are found  here [https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize+xy%5E2z%5E3+on+x%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2%3D6] and here [https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize+xy%5E2z%5E3+on+x%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2%3D6].

Comment: [continued] But WA also does not deal well with extrema that are "degenerate" in the sense of falling along entire curves, rather than just at single points.